# Show the label among the selections, depending on the radio-button clicked in TKinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having a problem with, only having a single label to show in an instance of clicking the radio button. I want to show that `label` depending with the `radio-button` I clicked, I tried reading about pack/grid_forget, but I think I still don't understand it pretty well, or I am just doing it really wrong in my code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# I squeezed them inside a frame, just for aesthetic reasons.
btn_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='', padx=20, pady=20)
btn_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# I use button widgets, instead of other widgets.Because I felt buttons are square, and they are easy 
to visualize.
red_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='R', padx=40, pady=40)
blue_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='B', padx=40, pady=40)
green_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='G', padx=40, pady=40)

red_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
blue_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
green_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)

def rad_btnClick(value):
    red_Btn_press_label = Label(root, text='You press R!', padx=40, bg='red')
    blu_Btn_press_label = Label(root, text='You press B!', padx=40, bg='blue')
    grn_Btn_press_label = Label(root, text='You press G!', padx=40, bg='green')

    if value == 1:
        red_Btn_press_label.grid(row=2, column=0,)
        red_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='r', padx=40, pady=40, bg='red')
        red_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        blu_Btn_press_label.grid_forget()
        grn_Btn_press_label.grid_forget()

    elif value == 2:
        blu_Btn_press_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
        blue_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='b', padx=40, pady=40, bg='blue')
        blue_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
        red_Btn_press_label.grid_forget()
        grn_Btn_press_label.grid_forget()

    elif value == 3:
        grn_Btn_press_label.grid(row=2, column=2)
        green_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='g', padx=40, pady=40, bg='green')
        green_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
        red_Btn_press_label.grid_forget()
        blu_Btn_press_label.grid_forget()


radiopress = IntVar()
# LABEL, VALUE, COLUMN
RAD_BUTTONS = [('RED BTN', 1, 0),
               ('BLU BTN', 2, 1),
               ('GRN BTN', 3, 2)]

for color, value, column in RAD_BUTTONS:
    rad_btn = Radiobutton(root, text=color, variable=radiopress,  value=value, command= lambda:rad_btnClick(radiopress.get()))
    rad_btn.grid(row=1, column=column)


root.mainloop()
```

So I am new in Python, I've just recently understood the 4/5 core fundamentals in every prog-language.
And now I am trying to learn about GUI with python, with Tkinter. I think my code got a bit longer, for something so simple and small. You can lecture my anyway you want, I just want learn good practices, and work on bad habits I may be doing.

Comment: In MY opinion, it would be better for you to have exactly ONE label, and in your button handler, just change the text and the color with `configure`.

Comment: And by the way, excuse me for interjecting my opinion, `tkinter` sucks.  It's actually running another language interpreter underneath (tcl), and sending shell commands to do the UI stuff.  Python has been trying to get rid of it for years.  If you're serious about Python, learn Qt or wxPython or some REAL UI.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will read more about configure and how I can use it. And I don't know much about creating GUIs with Python, but most recommendations I've come across always says TKinter. I am trying to make a desktop app, and right now I am learning about making GUIs with Python, so I started right away with TKinter from that experience. Are those you've mentioned great for creating desktop apps? If not I wish you could please recommend something I could start with.

Answer (score 0):

## I figured out that I should make my widgets global, and just make an update function to display every time an instance of them is created.

## I want to thank Tim Roberts for helping me.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

btn_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='', padx=20, pady=20)
btn_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

red_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='R', padx=40, pady=40)
blue_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='B', padx=40, pady=40)
green_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='G', padx=40, pady=40)

red_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
blue_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
green_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)

def rad_btnClick(value):
    global rad_btn_press_label
    global red_btn
    global blue_btn
    global green_btn

    if value == 1:
        rad_btn_press_label.grid_forget()
        rad_btn_press_label = Label(root, text='You press R!', padx=40, bg='red')
        red_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='R', padx=40, pady=40, bg='red')
        blue_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='B', padx=40, pady=40)
        green_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='G', padx=40, pady=40)

        rad_btn_press_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        red_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        blue_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
        green_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)

    elif value == 2:
        rad_btn_press_label.grid_forget()
        rad_btn_press_label = Label(root, text='You press R!', padx=40, bg='blue')
        red_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='R', padx=40, pady=40)
        blue_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='B', padx=40, pady=40, bg='blue')
        green_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='G', padx=40, pady=40)

        rad_btn_press_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
        red_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        blue_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
        green_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)

    elif value == 3:
        rad_btn_press_label.grid_forget()
        rad_btn_press_label = Label(root, text='You press G!', padx=40, bg='green')
        red_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='R', padx=40, pady=40)
        blue_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='B', padx=40, pady=40)
        green_btn = Button(btn_frame, text='G', padx=40, pady=40, bg='green')

        rad_btn_press_label.grid(row=2, column=2)
        red_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        blue_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
        green_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)

radiopress = IntVar()
# LABEL, VALUE, ROW, COLUMN
RAD_BUTTONS = [('RED BTN', 1, 1, 0),
               ('BLU BTN', 2, 1, 1),
               ('GRN BTN', 3, 1, 2)]

for color, value, row, column in RAD_BUTTONS:
    rad_btn = Radiobutton(root, text=color, variable=radiopress,  value=value, command=lambda: rad_btnClick(radiopress.get()))
    rad_btn.grid(row=row, column=column)

rad_btn_press_label = Label(root, text='You press R!', padx=40,)
rad_btn_press_label.grid(row=2, column=0, )
rad_btn_press_label.grid_forget()

root.mainloop()
```